# make a costume subploting from separate codes

Tags: python, plot, subplot

I have 4 codes, each one give me a plot.
I want to make costume 1 fig of this 4 plots.
I try with subplots but it's not ordinary variables so I don't know how to do that.
all of the codes id short.
thank you all!

[example of the final plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwvoC.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you read through this article at [delftstack.com](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/how-to-make-different-subplot-sizes-in-matplotlib/)

to clarify:

`plt.subplot2grid((10, 20), (0, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=10)`

first tuple is the total number of rows and columns (10,20)
the second tuple indicates the top left start of the graph
rowspan and colspan to indicate how far it streches

you create this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

# =====
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y = x ** 2
# =====

fig = plt.figure()


ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 20), (0, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=10)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 20), (5, 0), rowspan=5, colspan=10)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 20), (0, 10), rowspan=10, colspan=5)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 20), (0, 15), rowspan=10, colspan=5)

ax1.plot(x, y ,'r')
ax2.plot(x, y, 'b')
ax3.plot(x, y, 'y')
ax4.plot(x, y, 'g')


plt.show()
```